# Ada: optimize pragma

Tags: compilation, ada, pragma, optimization

in the quest to make an Ada code run faster, I'm including the pragma optimize time in the code (in the declarative part). On compiling in AdaGIDE using the GNAT Ada libre Core compiler, I get a warning message:

```
    pragma Optimize(Time);
       |
    >>> warning: insufficient -O value
```

In the Global settings in the AdaGIDE editor, I have Extensive (O2 level) enabled in the Optimization section.

The same code doesn't give any warning though on compilation in GPS. Any one here using AdaGIDE who had a similar experience before?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't use an IDE for Ada, but I was intrigued to see that the available option vary among GNAT versions: [4.3.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gcc.html#Switches-for-gcc), [4.4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gcc.html#Switches-for-gcc), and [4.5.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gcc.html#Switches-for-gcc). You might check which values apply to your installed version of the compiler versus what the IDE expects.

Comment: Thanks. I shall investigate this issue. But this is only a "warning" message and I can put the GNAT option -O3 in order to get full optimization (O3 = O2 + optimization for inline library units)

Comment: Emacs is an Integrated Development Environment. That's the IDE I use.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Not as portable, but well integrated, I use BBEdit or TextWrangler similarly On Mac OS X: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/misc/bbedit.html